# How to show TypeScript file output line number in Chrome DevTools Console with WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm, google-chrome-console

I'm expecting to see line number details in browser console as per `.ts` file, not `.js` file.

[image]

[image]

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

        /* Projects */
        // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
        // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
        // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
        // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
        // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
        // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

        /* Language and Environment */
        "target": "es2016",
        /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
        // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
        // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
        // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
        // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
        // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
        // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
        // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
        // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
        // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
        // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

        /* Modules */
        "module": "commonjs",
        /* Specify what module code is generated. */
        "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
        // "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
        // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
        // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
        // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
        // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
        // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
        // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
        // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
        // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
        // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

        /* JavaScript Support */
        // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
        // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
        // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

        /* Emit */
        // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
        // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
        // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
        "sourceMap": true /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */,
        // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
        "outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
        "removeComments": true /* Disable emitting comments. */,
        // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
        // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
        // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
        // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
        // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
        // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
        // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
        // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
        // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
        // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
        "noEmitOnError": true /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */,
        // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
        // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
        // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

        /* Interop Constraints */
        // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
        // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
        /* Type Checking */
        "strict": true,
        /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
        // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
        // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
        // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
        // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
        // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
        // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
        // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
        "noUnusedLocals": true /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */,
        "noUnusedParameters": true /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */,
        // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */,
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
        // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
        // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
        // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
        // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
        // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

        /* Completeness */
        // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
        "skipLibCheck": true

        /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    }
    //    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
    // Would be default but has to be included if exclude key is written

    //    "**/*.dev.ts" will mean this file format in any folder in this project.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `Sources` -> Both `Enable JavaScript source maps` and `Enable CSS source maps` **Unchecked** in Developer tools settings.